# What is the math behind ^^+ being replaced by k?

Tags: tex-core

In my readings I've come across that the TeX preprocessor replaces `^^+` with `k`.  The explanation given is the following:

> For instance, the sequence ^^+ is replaced by k because the ASCII
>   codes of k and + differ by 64. Since this replacement takes place
>   before tokens are formed, writing \vs^^+ip 5cm has the same effect as
>   \vskip 5cm.

I'm not a mathematician but I've looked at the ASCII table, and while I can see the ASCII codes of k with ASCII code of 107 and + with ASCII code of 43 differ by 64.

Yet I don't see what the mathematical relationship that he is describing is.  What is going on here?

Comment: There is no math behind it (beside substracting 64). It is simply a special input method. It is not really useful to input `k` in this way, but `^^M` e.g. is ASCII 13=CR and `^^J` is LF etc and it is quite useful to have a way to add them explictly in the code e.g. in error messages.

Comment: although the question is about another character value (`^^^M`), some of the explanation might be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/388563/579  (this is one of the questions listed under "related:; it *is* hard to search for this particilar type of "code" question.)

Comment: this covers it quite extensively: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62725/7674

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to know what happens with `^^<char>`, where `<char>` stands for a printable ASCII character (that is, between 32 and 126). The rule is simple: if `<code>` is the ASCII code for `<char>`, then there are two cases:

1. if `<code>` > 63, then `^^<char>` represents the ASCII character with code `<code>` - 64
2. if `<code>` ≤ 63, then `^^<char>` represents the ASCII character with code `<code>` + 64

However, if `<char>` is among `0123456789abcdef` and also the following character is in the same range, then `^^<char><char>` represents the character with ASCII code resulting from interpreting the two characters as hexadecimal digits.

Quoting the TeXbook (page 45):

> TeX has a standard way to refer to the invisible characters of ASCII:
>   Code 0 can be typed as the sequence of three characters `^^@`, code 1 can
>   be typed `^^A`, and so on up to code 31, which is `^^_` (see Appendix C).
>   If the character following `^^` has an internal code between 64 and 127, TeX
>   subtracts 64 from the code; if the code is between 0 and 63, TeX
>   adds 64. Hence code 127 can be typed `^^?`, and
>   the dangerous bend sign can be obtained by saying
>   `{\manual^^?}`. However, you must change the category code of character
>   127 before using it, since this character ordinarily has category 15
>   (invalid); say, e.g., `` \catcode`\^^?=12 ``.
>
> [...]
>
> There's also a special convention in which `^^` is
>   followed by *two* “lowercase hexadecimal digits,” `0`–`9` or `a`–`f`.
>   With this convention, all 256 characters are obtainable in a uniform
>   way, from `^^00` to `^^ff`. Character 127 is `^^7f`.