# Maximum amount of characters per line in .tex-input files?

Tags: tex-core, write

According to TeXbook TeX does preprocess files of .tex-input line per line (converting all characters of the line to TeX's internal character-representation-scheme (ASCII or Unicode), truncating sequences of space-characters at ends of lines, appending a character specified by `\endlinechar`).

So questions arise:

1. What is the maximum amount of characters per line in .tex-input files?
2. How does TeX behave when encountering at reading-time a line that is too long?

You can use TeX for writing external text files.

3. How does TeX behave when attempting to write a line to external text file that is too long/that has more characters than TeX can place into a single line of an external text file?

The `\write`-primitive always writes an entire line to external text-file.

4. Are there means for

   - just beginning  a new line of an external text-file?
   - appending characters to the current line of an external text-file?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a limit.  I certainly have a line of over 1300 characters in one file in my thesis (a `\caption`, including cross-references, equations, `\label` and a lot of edits highlighted using the `changes` package; I tend to write one sentence per line)

Comment: Given @David's answer below, I feel like I wasn't even trying

Comment: @ChrisH my test file had 400000 `z` followed by `\bye`

Comment: I am not sure I understand all your `\write` questions, you can write a newline by writing the `\newlinechar` (`^^J` in laTeX) try `\typeout{aaa^^Jbbb}`

Comment: While 200000 is the nominal limit, with 199990 characters in a line you still get the error, and running `pdflatex` on a file starting with `199989` times the letter `z`, I get an `! Emergency stop` error for some reason...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I think with less than 2000000 it reads the line but then you kill its hyphenation pass

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But it dies with `Emergency stop` right after the everypar error (add a line with `\tracingall` before the 199989 `z`s), so I think it's something else internal (seems like an off-by-one error somewhere)

Comment: I tried to reproduce but didn't get that (I had  also tried adding `\tracingall` don't all tex files have that?) I was using pdftex cygwin tl2021 with 199989z and \bye on the same line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is system dependent and with web2c implementations user-settable.

texlive 2021 `texmf.cnf` has

```
% Buffer size.  TeX uses the buffer to contain input lines, but macro
% expansion works by writing material into the buffer and reparsing the
% line.  As a consequence, certain constructs require the buffer to be
% very large, even though most documents can be handled with a small value.
buf_size = 200000
```

If you exceed this you get:

```
$ pdftex aa408
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./aa408.tex! Unable to read an entire line---bufsize=200000.
Please increase buf_size in texmf.cnf.
```

TeX has no mechanism to append to a file.

Comment: Thanks for answering. As to "TeX has no mechanism to append to a file."  The question is not about appending to a *file* but about appending to a *line* as could, e.g., be done with Pascal's `write`-procedure which - unlike `writeln` - does not finish the line.

Comment: What happens if you have accumulated tokens for writing in an amount where the resulting amount of characters to be written to external file has more characters than TeX's `\write` can write into a single line?

Comment: @Mrs.MarsupialWallaby for the log file you can use `\message` instead of `\write` for any other files then no it's not possible, but of course you can manage that via macros save up the tokens to be written in a token register then write them once you want to finish a line

Comment: @Mrs.MarsupialWallaby the tokens to be written are accumulated in the input buffer before`\write` gets them so I think you will always get the error I showed even on writing.

Comment: Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: Is "macro expansion works by writing material into the buffer and reparsing the line" actually true? Doesn't TeX just start reading from a token list?

Comment: @texdr.aft normally yes but I seem to think that comment is right and there are constructs where tex borrows the input buffer, a couple of quick examples failed to show this howerever, and it's a bit late at night to start reading tex.web:-)

Comment: @texdr.aft ah  \input triggers this if you have `\input file` followed by z to say column 199980 then if `file.tex` is just `x` it all works but make it 20 x then you get the unable to read entire line error even though neither file has a line that long

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Also, the name manufactured by `\csname`...`\endcsname` gets put in the buffer (section 374, comment on `buf_size` in section 11)