# Recursively update macro

Tags: math-mode, macros

I would like to store and recursively update mathematical expressions in a macro `\temp` using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\temp{}
\def\update#1_#2{
    \xdef\temptemp{\temp}
    \gdef\temp{\temptemp\frac{#1}{#2}}}
    
\update{a}_{b}
\[\temp\]

\update{c}_{d}
\[\temp\]
\end{document}
```

This code works well and gives a/b and a/b c/d.

However, once I change `\frac{#1}{#2}` to `\underbrace{#1}_{#2}`, it returns an error "! Illegal parameter number in definition of `\temptemp`."

What's the problem and how can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw, that’s not a recursion, which requires calling itself AND an end condition.

Comment: Not the main error but see also [symbols - What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: unrelated but I wouldn't use a generic macros name like `\temp` to store content that should stay. That is a name other commands can easily internally use for "temporary" content too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code *seems* to work. Let's add some tracing in order to better see what happens:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\temp{}
\def\update#1_#2{
    \xdef\temptemp{\temp}
    \gdef\temp{\temptemp\frac{#1}{#2}}}
    
\update{a}_{b}
\texttt{\meaning\temp}
\[\temp\]

\update{c}_{d}
\texttt{\meaning\temp}
\[\temp\]

\update{e}_{f}
\texttt{\meaning\temp}
\[\temp\]

\texttt{\meaning\temptemp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, you're not updating `\temp` with the new part; you're updating `\temptemp` actually. And the last part in the image shows that you're not really getting `\frac{a}{b}`, but what `\xdef` does with it, which is somewhat unpredictable due to the fact that the vast majority of typesetting commands are not supposed to be used in `\edef` or `\xdef`. And it goes much worse with `\underbrace`.

You don't really need anything special: the LaTeX kernel has `\g@addto@macro`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\container}{}
\newcommand\update{}
\makeatletter
\def\update#1_#2{%
  \g@addto@macro\container{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% just for this example

\begin{document}

\update{a}_{b}
\texttt{\meaning\container}
\[\container\]

\update{c}_{d}
\texttt{\meaning\container}
\[\container\]

\update{e}_{f}
\texttt{\meaning\container}
\[\container\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are doing full expansion (`\xdef`) of previous macro declated by `\update` but `\underbrace` is more complicated macro which uses `\halign` with `#` in its preamble and this cannot be fully expanded without immediately processing.

You can update the list of math formulae without expansion:

```
\def\update#1_#2{\addto\temp{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}
```

where `\addto` is defined by:

```
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
```

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of `long`?

Comment: @projetmbc Generally-speaking the TeXbook/TeX by topic contains info on such "low-level" commands.

Comment: @projetmbc The `\long` is not needed in you case, but I copied it from my set of usable macos, where `\addto` is ready to add the `\par` to the existing macro too. Normally `\par` raises error "paragraph ended before macro is complete". The TeX in a Nutshell http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf describes such "low-level" commands too.

Answer (score 3):

`underbrace` is a robust command protected by LaTeX's `\protect` mechanism. For the mechanism to work properly you need the `protected@` functions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\temp{}

\makeatletter

\def\update#1_#2{%
    \protected@xdef\temptemp{\temp}%
    \gdef\temp{\temptemp\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}

    
\update{a}_{b}
\[\temp\]

\update{c}_{d}
\[\temp\]
\end{document}
```

Expansion control in TeX is complex. Also, in this case you don't need x-expansion at all. There are dedicated macros for this purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\def\temp{}

\makeatletter

\def\update#1_#2{%
    \appto\temp{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}

    
\update{a}_{b}
\[\temp\]

\update{c}_{d}
\[\temp\]
\end{document}
```

Or see `\tl_put_right:Nn` in expl3 but there are some "complications" with the catcode of the underscore here.

Comment: See also [macros - What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands? When and why do we need \protect? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands-when-and-why-do-we-n?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [macros - Minimal \protected@edef example - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5693/minimal-protectededef-example?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Actually `frac` is also a old-style-protected macro but it happens to work here.

Comment: Side note, if you're using plain-TeX-style solutions, you'd better be good at TeX programming or be prepared for confusing error messages. "dedicated LaTeX" solutions are more likely to be tested with existing packages/commands etc..

Answer (score 3):

`\temp` with many LaTeX-packages is a scratch-macro. So code not stemming from you might override (re)definitions of `\temp` stemming from code written by you.

In order to prevent such clashes in the following `\Mytemp` is used instead of `\temp`.

Donald E. Knuth in his TeXbook describes TeX analogously to a beast which has eyes, mouth and digestive tract.

I tried to outline the different stages of the processing of a .tex-file, using that analogy, in my answers to

- [Conversion of space characters into space tokens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516129/118714)
- [Define commands without the need for brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552175/118714)
- ['a^^Mb' isn't equivalent to 'ab'; instead throws pdftex into an extended mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/601364)

With `\def`/`\gdef` expansion is suppressed while tokens forming the definition text go down TeX's gullet. Thus with `\def`/`\gdef` the tokens forming the definition text are not expanded when reaching the stomach where performing the assignment takes place.

With `\edef`/`\xdef` expansion is not suppressed while tokens forming the definition text go down TeX's gullet. Thus with `\edef`/`\xdef` the tokens forming the definition text in a "process of regurgitation" are "fully" expanded when reaching the stomach where performing the assignment takes place.

The crucial point is: `\underbrace` itself is a macro which at some stage of expansion yields some `#`. At the time when expansion is done and in TeX's stomach the attempt of performing the assignment underlying `\xdef` takes place, these `#` erroneously are taken for reference to some parameter of the macro that is to be defined/redefined.

Besides this you might like to cope with the fact that definitions can be nested inside definitions whereby which each "nesting-level" another level of doubling hashes for denoting parameters of the definition in that definition-level is needed and with the fact that expanding a macro reduces two consecutive hashes occurring in that macro's definition text the a single hash.

E.g., if you do

```tex
\long\def\hashcarrier{################A}
\long\xdef\hashcarrier{\hashcarrier B}
\show\hashcarrier
\long\xdef\hashcarrier{\hashcarrier C}
\show\hashcarrier
\long\xdef\hashcarrier{\hashcarrier D}
\show\hashcarrier
%% If you activate the following lines you get error-message about 
%% illegal parameter number in definition of \hashcarrier because 
%% things were reduced to single hashes that are taken for reference 
%% to parameters of the current definition-level while the parameter-text
%% of the current definition-level doesn't denote any parameter at all
%% and parameters must be numbered consecutively from 1 to 9 instead of
%% a thing like A:
%\long\xdef\hashcarrier{\hashcarrier E}
%\show\hashcarrier
\csname bye\endcsname
\stop
```

you get the following output on terminal / in .log-file

```
> \hashcarrier=\long macro:
->########AB.
l.3 \show\hashcarrier
                     
? 
> \hashcarrier=\long macro:
->####ABC.
l.5 \show\hashcarrier
                     
? 
> \hashcarrier=\long macro:
->##ABCD.
l.7 \show\hashcarrier
                     
?
```

(`\long` means that in case the macro in question processes arguments each of these arguments may contain the control-word-token `\par`.)

You can prevent both unwanted expansion and reducing amount of hashes via `\xdef` and `\unexpanded`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\Mytemp{}%
\long\def\updateMytemp#1_#2{%
  \long\xdef\Mytemp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\Mytemp\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}%
}%

\begin{document}

\updateMytemp{a}_{b}
\show\Mytemp
\[\Mytemp\]

\updateMytemp{c}_{d}
\show\Mytemp
\[\Mytemp\]
\end{document}
```

Or --legacy style-- via `\xdef` and `\the`-expansion of a token-register:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks\MyScratchtoks
\newcommand\Mytemp{}%
\long\def\updateMytemp#1_#2{%
  \MyScratchtoks\expandafter{\Mytemp\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}%
  \long\xdef\Mytemp{\the\MyScratchtoks}%
}%

\begin{document}

\updateMytemp{a}_{b}
\show\Mytemp
\[\Mytemp\]

\updateMytemp{c}_{d}
\show\Mytemp
\[\Mytemp\]

\end{document}
```

I suggest doing something more generic using LaTeX's `\g@addto@macro`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\Mytemp{}%
\makeatletter\newcommand\updateMytemp[1]{\g@addto@macro{\Mytemp}{#1}}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\updateMytemp{\underbrace{a}_{b}}
\show\Mytemp
\[\Mytemp\]

\updateMytemp{\underbrace{c}_{d}}
\show\Mytemp
\[\Mytemp\]
\end{document}
```

With all three examples you get something like the following messages on console and in the .log-file:

```
> \Mytemp=macro:
->\underbrace {a}_{b}.
l.9 \show\Mytemp
              
? 
> \Mytemp=macro:
->\underbrace {a}_{b}\underbrace {c}_{d}.
l.13 \show\Mytemp
```

With all three examples you get the following pdf-output:

[image]

Another hint:

LaTeX's `\newcommand`, `\NewDocumentCommand` etc trigger error-messages in case the command to be defined is already defined or cannot be defined due to containing the leading phrase "end" in its name. You can achieve the same behavior with assignments performed via `\def`/`\gdef`/`\edef`/`\xdef` by wrapping them into LaTeX's `\@ifdefinable`-test.

E.g., instead of just

```latex
\long\def\updateMytemp#1_#2{%
  \long\xdef\Mytemp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\Mytemp\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}%
}%
```

you would do

```latex
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\updateMytemp}{%
  \long\def\updateMytemp#1_#2{%
    \long\xdef\Mytemp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\Mytemp\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother
```

If you wonder what `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` is about:

Simplified speaking TeX/LaTeX usually allow only ordinary alphabetic letters `a..z`/`A..Z` as components of names of control-word-tokens.

`\makeatletter` is a directive for telling LaTeX that henceforth `@` shall be allowed as component of names of control-word-tokens, too.

`\makeatother`  is a directive for telling LaTeX that henceforth `@` shall a be thing which is not allowed as component of names of control-word-tokens.

Without `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` you could use `\csname..\endcsname` for gathering the name of the control sequence token from what is between `\csname..\endcsname`  and delivering that control sequence token:

```latex
\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname{\updateMytemp}{%
  \long\def\updateMytemp#1_#2{%
    \long\xdef\Mytemp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\Mytemp\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}%
  }%
}%
```