# Scantokens and Newlines

Tags: sourcecode, e-tex

I'm having problems with the usage of scantokens. I'm trying to convert a list that I read in while under the effects of `\obeylines`. For some reason, any time I use scantokens on my list, it stops reading at the `^^M`.

Observe:

```
{\obeylines%
  \gdef\one{\message{foo}
    \message{bar}}
}
    \one
\expandafter\scantokens\expandafter{\one}
\bye
```

gives the output 
    (./scan.tex foo bar foo )

As in, it won't put out the second bar.

This is a simplified example. But it could come up practically if you're reading in a paragraph line by line, and the `^^M` ends up coming into your token stream because it was hidden by braces.

In any case, it's a bit inconvenient for `\scantokens` to just drop out on you like that.

Comment: See also: [tex core - New lines and TeX: difference between ^^J and ^^M - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8967/new-lines-and-tex-difference-between-j-and-m?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to change the `\newlinechar`. This ensures that any `^^M` that is in the stream to be read in gets interpreted as  a newline rather than an end of line. An end of line character in the middle of a line is treating as if a comment character were there, and the rest of the line, until the newline character, is ignored.

If you add

```
\newlinechar=13 %that's the character code of newline
```

to the line before the scantokens, then you get the correct output.