# Listing inside loop body

Tags: listings, loops

I want a listing in the body of a loop.
E.g. write something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \lstset{escapechar=|}
    \newcounter{test}
    \@whilesw{\ifnum\value{test}<3}\fi{
        \stepcounter{test}
        \begin{lstlisting}
|\roman{test}|
        \end{lstlisting}
    }
\end{document}
```

instead of

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    \lstset{escapechar=|}
    \newcounter{test}
    \stepcounter{test}
    \begin{lstlisting}
|\roman{test}|
    \end{lstlisting}
    \stepcounter{test}
    \begin{lstlisting}
|\roman{test}|
    \end{lstlisting}
    \stepcounter{test}
    \begin{lstlisting}
|\roman{test}|
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When (La)TeX scans the parameter of a macro, it fixes the catcodes of the characters/tokens it reads. So when the second parameter for `\@whilesw` is scanned, all special characters will be processed as if they were normal LaTeX code. This clashes with verbatim environments which rely on changing catcodes later on to typeset special characters properly. In this example this is especially problematic because `listings` can't recognoize `\end{lstlisting}` as the end of the listing anymore.

A solution is to read the listing's code under a catcode regime where every character has catcode 12 (other) and thus handles them in no special way. We can use the `filecontentsdefmacro` environment from the `filecontentsdef` package for this purpose to store the code in a macro `\lsttemplate`. The second step is to re-apply the normal catcode regime when that code is actually processed to make the `lstlisting` environment actually do its job. This can be done using the ε-TeX primtitive `\scantokens`

The complete solution looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontentsdef}

\begin{filecontentsdefmacro}\lsttemplate
\begin{lstlisting}
\roman{test} --> |\roman{test}|
\end{lstlisting}
\end{filecontentsdefmacro}

\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \lstset{escapechar=|, basicstyle=\ttfamily}
    \newcounter{test}
    \@whilesw{\ifnum\value{test}<3}\fi{
        \stepcounter{test}
        \scantokens\expandafter{\lsttemplate}
    }
\end{document}
```

outputs

> [image]

Comment: Thanks, this did solve my problem. I'd like to point out one caveat though. The filecontentsdefmacro may not contain a comment. [The problem with comments in scantokens is outlined here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8967/new-lines-and-tex-difference-between-j-and-m). Comments work in the `scontents` solution by Pablo González L.

Answer (score 2):

Same result as @siracusa, but using the `scontents` package (inspired by `filecontentsdef`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[store-env=lsttemplate]{scontents}

\begin{scontents}
\begin{lstlisting}
\roman{test} --> |\roman{test}|
\end{lstlisting}
\end{scontents}

\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \lstset{escapechar=|, basicstyle=\ttfamily}
    \newcounter{test}
    \@whilesw{\ifnum\value{test}<3}\fi{
        \stepcounter{test}
        \getstored[1]{lsttemplate}
    }
\end{document}
```